# Does DGML support different shapes?

Tags: static-analysis, dgml

I've started to play with DGML, and I see in the [schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml/dgml.xsd) that the `Node` element supports a `Shape` attribute.

I've tried things like
`<Node Shape='square'...` with no effect.

Is Shape really supported in DGML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't appear to be able to get the shape attribute to affect anything either.

I assume you are using the new VS2010 viewer?

The following [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842619.aspx) (which is a pretty handy reference, actually) does give this example:

> Set the Shape property to None so that
>   the icon replaces the shape. Use the
>   Icon property to specify the location
>   of the icon.

This does appear to work - setting shape="none" removes the shape.

It is likely that support for displaying different shapes has not been implemented in the viewer yet, so only 'none' makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

For rectangles, you can use       <Setter Property="NodeRadius" Value="0" />.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider reading:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsarch/thread/84400dea-3426-4e0e-8271-6af52ae1d1fb

about my DSL that maps some shapes to attributes (though there is no software there as yet)
[image: Shapes]